# How to understand the CRC Algorithm from the CAN specification?

Tags: crc

I am trying to understand how the cyclic redundancy check (CRC) algorithm from [the Controller Area Network (CAN) specification](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf) works. Here is the pseudocode.

`CRC_RG = 0;                         // initialize shift register
REPEAT
CRCNXT = NXTBIT EXOR CRC_RG(14);
CRC_RG(14:1) = CRC_RG(13:0);        // shift left by
CRC_RG(0) = 0;                      // 1 position
IF CRCNXT THEN
   CRC_RG(14:0) = CRC_RG(14:0) EXOR (4599hex);
ENDIF
UNTIL (CRC SEQUENCE starts or there is an ERROR condition)`

I do understand the standard algorithms but not the CAN algorithm. I have calculated it by hand and programmed it and it works fine. I just don't understand why/how it works.

Comment: What is `NXTBIT` initialised to?

Comment: @PeterTaylor NXTBIT is a *function* reading next bit of input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRC(x) is remainder of polynomial division of `x` by some fixed polynomial. Here bits of `x`, as well as bits of result, represents polynomial with binary coefficients, f.e. 0b101 may represent polynomial `1*x^2 + 0*x + 1`.

So, the algorithm you have cited, is the most straightforward one - if `q(x) = p(x) mod f(x)`, then `p(x)*x mod f(x)` is either just `q(x)*x` (if it doesn't contain `x^N` where N is order of f(x) polynomial), or `q(x)*x - x^N + (x^N mod f(x))`. As you may note, the last sum component is some fixed polynomial for given `f(x)`.

So, each step of this cycle do the following:

- shift result by 1 bit left - equivalent to multiplication by `x`
- if result contains `x^N` then xor result by `x^N mod f(x)`

Oh, well, there are some more details. Please read [*a painless guide to CRC error detection algorithms*](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) for real explanation.

Comment: I have read the painless guide but you explained it better. I understand it now. Thank you.